# Is the MacBook Pro Retina (Old Version) meant to come with an extension cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, power, accessories

Is this **Apple MacBook Pro ME665LL/A 15.4-Inch Laptop with Retina Display (Old version)** meant to come with an extension cable to plug into this charger?

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LAO6806) is the cable I think is missing from my package, and the [cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD506LL/A/apple-85w-magsafe-2-power-adapter-for-macbook-pro-with-retina-display) I got:

Answer (score 1):

Correct - you are a missing that component. *Assuming you purchased directly from Apple*, You’re supposed to get the magsafe, as well as the extension AC adaptor. Contact Apple support or visit your local Apple store if applicable.